# Largest and smallest eigenvectors are minimizers of the $2$-norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm trying to minimize $ v^TLv $ over all unit $v$'s, where $L$ is symmetric positive definite. and also trying to maximize it. It turns out the this statement is at its maximum when you pick the largest eigenvector, and smallest when you pick the smallest (nonzero) eigenvector.

I think you do it with SVD/PCA but I'm not quite sure how. note: it's the same as maximizing the $L^2$ norm of $\|Av\|$ where $L = A^TA$, which is possible by spectral decomposition.

edit: by largest eigenvector, i mean the unit eigenvector corresponding to the largest eigenvalue

Comment: There is no   such a notion of largest or smallest *eigenvectors*.

Comment: What is the question?